# How to fill the white spaces out with divs

Tags: css

How to fill the white spaces out with divs?

I need that the divs behave like where each of them fill out the white spaces. So, if needed, the div goes to the top, joining the div above, but I get this, wherever if I use `float: left` or `display: inline-block/inline`

```css
main {
  font-size: 0;
}
main > div {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
main > div:nth-child(4n+1) {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
main > div:nth-child(4n+2) {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
main > div:nth-child(4n+3) {
  height: 300px;
  background: orange;
}
main > div:nth-child(4n+4) {
  height: 150px;
  background: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks @somethinghere, I'll search about it.

Comment: @somethinghere If you don't understand what flexbox is or how it works, don't recommend it.

Comment: wont be possible in CSS

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that layout you will need to use some javascript logic.
CSS alone will not allow you to position elements of different heights like that.

One recommendation would be [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which will do the heaving lifting for you and will calculate the appropriate position for your elements and then apply `position: absolute;` and set the `top` and `left` css properties on them.

> Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in use all over the Internet.

Comment: While this may provide a solution to the problem above, Stack Overflow is a site for specific and detailed answers that stand on their own. Without your link (even with it, actually), your answer is nothing more than a library recommendation, and is better served as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @TylerH I have updated the answer. You are right my original answer wasn't providing any useful information.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll see it! @ionutvmi